# Making a rest call to get the total number of items

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to building REST services and am following [this guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) to create a .net client in c# to call a service that accepts REST calls to it.

I can make get requests from my code to get single items such as :

```
api/products/1
```

using this code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
}
```

My goal here is to not list just 1 item but every item. I know in the URI i can normally type

```
api/products
```

to get a full list of items, but in the code above I cannot store all of those in the response variable.

So my question is maybe 2 parts:

1. Can a HttpResponseMessage be an array? Can I call api/products and have it work that way?
2. Is there a method I can request for it to return the total number of items so I can use that later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `api/products` endpoint returns, for example, a JSON array of `Product` elements, then you can simply do this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    List<Product> products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}",
            product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```